# Hide footer in canva embed

Tags: javascript, css

I have embedded a canva template into a website. There is a footer that I'm trying to hide, but all the classes and id tags are generated through javascript. How would I hide a class when it is created dynamically through a javascript script that I don't have access to?

This is how the element looks once it is generated

```
.T68fnw{
font-size: 62.5%;
user-select: none;
-webkit-tap-highlight-color: transparent;
z-index: 1;
}
```

This is the div tag that I'm trying to hide as it contains all the footer information inside of it.

```
<div class="T68fnw"><div class="CoORvg">Other footer information held within this div</div></div>
```

I have tried doing display: none; in css as well as doing it in javascript on page load both have not returned the desired result.

Comment: Provide us the HTML of the elements you're trying to remove.

Comment: @Nanoo I have included the div tag that I'm tying to hide.

Comment: @DominikWillaford if you can't use the id, you might want to use the place within the other elements  where your div resides. Maybe it's the last div, or some other fixed place, or maybe it's always after a div with a certain content.

Comment: @Marko do you think it's possible to use an XPath to hide the div tag. Everything is setup using classes, not id tags. Unless it possible to dynamically add a ID tag to the div tag.

Comment: If you want a solution, you will need to give me the full HTML (with the div tag in it)

Comment: You said that the ids/classes are generate through JavaScript, so the class "`.T68fnw`" isnt very useful...

Comment: @Nanoo I forgot to wrap the div inside of the code symbols, but I included the div and the child div in my edit.

Comment: Does the div actually contain "Other footer information held within this div"? I need all of the HTML within it if possible.

Comment: @DominikWillaford did you manage to figure out?